# Do Vue single file components (.vue files) have to `export default` or can they use named exports?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

`export default` seems to be an obsolete and discouraged way to export modules.
For example:

- https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad
- https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad

However when I change my all my Vue components from this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
'use strict';
import {store} from '../../data/store';
const c = { 'data': store };
export default c; // <-- HERE
</script>
```

to this

```js
<script lang="ts">
'use strict';
import {store} from '../../data/store';
const c = { 'data': store };
export {c as headerBar}; // <-- HERE
</script>
```

I get `dateWidget.vue:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefine` in the browser.

Why is this happening and is there any way to use proper modern exports with Vue and Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually defined in the [Vue SFC spec](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#script) itself so I don't think there's a way around it ..

> The default export should be a [Vue.js component options object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data). Exporting an extended constructor created by `Vue.extend()` is also supported, but a plain object is preferred.